# Cosmos DB connector Continuation Token too large

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure Logic app that uses the Cosmos DB Query documents V5 connector. If I do more than a simple query with one condition in the where clause, the continuation token remains small. Adding any further conditions to the where clauses result in the Continuation Token to be too large to transmit for the next request. On the next search, I receive a 400 Bad Request - Request Too Long.

I have searched in web and have found how to fix the issue via C# code by setting the ResponseContinuationTokenLimitInKb, but that does me no good in the logic app.

Answer (score 0):

We faced similar issues in our system. But ours was function app. So we made use of ResponseContinuationTokenLimitInKb like this,

```
    var queryRequestOptions = new QueryRequestOptions
    {
        PartitionKey = partitionKey,
        MaxItemCount = 400,
        ResponseContinuationTokenLimitInKb = 1
    };
```

You also can strip the continuation token and use it instead of the entire token by removing #FPC. Please keep in mind that in some cases you might get #FPP too.

Last but not least. Did you try using DirectConnection (WithConnectionModeDirect) ?